# Background image animation using css3 or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, background-image, css-animations

can anyone help me about how to animate a background image like on this website

http://breakpoint-sass.com/

on the credits section the background image seems moving, i don't know if it is using css3 or jquery.

And is there any tutorial on how to do it or via using plugin.

Many thanks.

Comment: :) It's a simple **.gif animation** http://breakpoint-sass.com/images/point-break/sky-circle.gif?1358149772

Comment: thanks for your answer, yeah i inspect the element and the image is in .gif format, is there a way to do it on css3 or ready made effects?

Comment: sure, lemme show you, sec

Comment: Thanks again, where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple demo of animating a BG sprite image

http://jsbin.com/ohulok/1/edit

```
var c = 0 ;
function loop(){
  c = ++c%5;
  $('#bird').css({backgroundPosition: (240*c)+'px 0px'});
}
setInterval(loop, 42);
```

Info: if you want a 24fps rate that's ~42 (41.666ms)

**http://jsbin.com/ohulok/7/edit**

Comment: Cool!, so you need to create a series of action of an image then the script will do the flying thing?..

Comment: many3x thanks, you're great!, need to learn this shared stuff from you

Comment: @user2074113 yes, That was an example using 'sprite' image. but you can use the similar logic and `.animate()` and just move a background

Comment: ok got it, thanks again for the knowledge and stuff..:)

Comment: @user2074113 look here: http://jsbin.com/ohulok/4/edit

Comment: yeah so this is using the .animate, how about combinig the two, while the bird moves from the left at the same time the feathers move too?

Comment: Actually im a newbie to pure javascript coding, im used only using jquery plugin which are easy to configure..

Comment: @user2074113 take a look at this demo, the boat moves too! http://jsbin.com/ohulok/9/edit

Comment: Oh man, im getting crazy with all the stuff you do..haha..I need more rice to consume all of this great2x stuff you've shared..:)

Comment: Yeah, i think so far im not violating some of those

Comment: there you go..many thanks again