# Animate the image of a hand to make it wave using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'd like to animate the hand of a character to make it like if it was waving at somebody, using jQuery.
I've tried to swap 2 images (a hand poiting to the left and a hand pointing to the right). But it's not very smooth...
Is there a better solution? I've also tried to use a jQuery plugin to rotate the image, but I couldn't find a plugin which works (& compatible with IE8).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know Flash, so I thought about jQuery (all the other animations of the projet are done with jQuery too). And I can't use CSS3 as it's not compatible with IE8. Is there another easy option?

Comment: how about an animated gif?

Comment: You would need at least three, maybe more frames to have a "smooth" animation. You can also use the "sprite" technique.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, create an image sprite

> [hand 1/7][hand 2/7][hand 3/7][hand 4/7][hand 5/7][hand 6/7][hand 7/7]

all in one image, set the boundary for your hand into an element and using jquery just loop the background position of your element.

This answer should get you started:
 **[Background image animation using css3 or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887331/background-image-animation-using-css3-or-jquery)**

```
var c = 0 ;
function loop(){
  c = ++c % 7; // Reminder the number of images (7)
  $('#hand').css({backgroundPosition: (240*c)+'px 0px'}); // 240 = one image/sprite width
}
setInterval(loop, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

as roXon says, you can do like that and this can be also useful:  [jQuery GIF Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628576/jquery-gif-animations) take a look

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 [animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)/[transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/) can create the animation

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfzc2/7/)</kbd>

```
.waving-anim {
    animation:wave 500ms infinite;
    transform-origin:bottom left;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(3deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(-3deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(3deg);
    }
}
```

does require vendor prefixes (see demo) and is supported in current browsers (IE10 included)